# How to run script on Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: gcloud, gcsfuse

Recently I am using Google Cloud Storage to store some files. I have used Cloud Storage Fuse to mount it with my instance from Google Compute Engine. When I try to run my own script in the bucket, it does not allow to do so even if I use chmod a+x. Is there any way to authorise it? Thanks!

P.S.Below is the script I want to run

```
mkdir -p PB_report_0208/shortest_path
cp ./tag_1/shortest_path.csv ./PB_report_0208/shortest_path/shortest_path1.csv
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/gcsfuse/blob/941ac7e9afb3ef89a51100e10b418e1f90c22388/docs/semantics.md#inodes), gcsfuse doesn't track permissions bits, so your `chmod` command isn't doing anything. You can use the gcsfuse `--file-mode` to give all files the execute bit (but not on a file-by-file basis).